# Default view in spring web app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to call a controller by default in my app when it starts.
Something like when the app runs it goes into following controller by default.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
 public ModelAndView home(){  
 }
```

I have tried giving "home" in welcome file list in web.xml but its not working.
And i don't want to use "/". Is it possible??
Please help

Comment: why you don't you want to use `/`?

Answer (score 0):

In `default.jsp`, have a redirect to `/home`, as follows:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:redirect url="/home" />
```

Comment: Right idea, but I would strongly suggest using `jsp:forward` instead of a redirect.